# How to change the face emotion with a single image?

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I have a face image, and I found the 68 facial coordinate points with dlib libarary in python.
[image: I mean these interest point on the face]

Now I want to change the face emotion by closing the mouth, for ex. remove the distance between points[61, 62,63,64,65,66,67,68,68], or closing the right eye by removing the distance between points:[43,44,..,48]

So, I need to to color this area with natural colors in a way that it seems natural.

is there any method or algorithm available to solve it? I use openCV right now,but any other  library is okay for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is run your facial coordinate points detection algorithm on the images in this data set: https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/FER-2013, which contains images for seven emotions (happiness, neutral, sadness, anger, surprise, disgust, fear).

Like that you could maybe infer the transformation from the neutral face to one of this emotion.